# usefulness of "most general queries" in prolog?

Tags: prolog

In prolog a **most general query** is one in which every parameter is an ungrounded variable.

For example, `?- reversed(X,Y)` is a most general query, whereas `?- reversed([1,2,3], Y)` is not.

**Question:** What is the precise benefit of most general queries?

I'd like to think the answer is something like "a most general query **maximally tests** the (generality of?) definitions of a prolog program entailed by the query". However I am not sure if this is too brave an answer.

Comment: Erm.... "To be able to list potential problem solution structures despite no data information provided" maybe?

Comment: Doesn't it make you feel good to say it? "Most general query"? It makes me feel clever every time I write it down, even now. And the feeling when you write a predicate and it terminates with a correct answer when you give it the most general query (aah)? Better than sax music. In short, I find it so useful. The most general query.

Comment: hi @TA_intern that is indeed the feeling I get! However, due to my limited talents, I'm unable to write down in precise words what the benefits of a MGQ are. Naively I thought, "does it test all code paths" or the "generality of the definitions" .. but that feels insufficiently accurate. Let me put it another way - what does a successful MGQ test that a successful non-MGQ doesn't test?

Comment: It tests whether *any* solution is possible.